# Android and sendOrderedBroadcast - how to immediately get the results?

Tags: android, events, event-handling

In some cases I need to get data from misc intents and try to use sendOrderedBroadcast. But this call is async, and I don't know how to wait for it. I try:

```
onCreate(...)
{
    // ...
    sendOrderedBroadcast(...);
    if (someResult!=null)
        {
            // Never executed
        }
    // ...
}

onButtonPressed(...)
{
    if (someResult!=null)
        {
            // Often fires
        }
}
```

I think I need to call something like Windows message loop

```
while (::PeekMessage(...)) 
    {
        GetMessage(...);
    }
```

after sendOrderedBroadcast and before using someResult.

How I can do it? Or, is there more convenient and right way?

**UPD** More details

```
public class DetailsChecker extends BroadcastReceiver{
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
        // ...
}

// ...

sendOrderedBroadcast(detailsIntent, null, new DetailsChecker(), null,
            Activity.RESULT_OK, null, null);
```

Comment: use a resultReceiver parameter

Comment: so you know that broadcast was received when DetailsChecker.onReceive is called,  right?

Comment: Yes, I know it. The onReceive event occurs after onCreate returns, but I need the data in onCreate.

Comment: no you can't get it in onCreate,  this is an async operation and you cannot stop the ui thread waiting for results, all you can do is to perform some action in DetailsChecker.onReceive

Comment: @pskink It is actually possible, see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it is possible. You can specify a handler that will receive the response in sendOrderedbroadcast, so you can receive it on another thread and block the UI thread while the broadcast is being processed. Something like that:

```
    final Object monitor = new Object();
    HandlerThread thread = new HandlerThread("blabla");
    thread.start();
    synchronized (monitor) {
        Intent intent = new Intent("nanana");
        context.sendOrderedBroadcast(intent,
                null,
                new BroadcastReceiver() {
                    @Override
                    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                        // mystuff
                        someResult = tagada;
                        synchronized(monitor) {
                            monitor.notify();
                        }
                    }
                },
                new Handler(thread.getLooper()),
                Activity.RESULT_OK,
                null,
                null
        );
        try {
            monitor.wait(2000); // timeout for receiving the result
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
    }
    thread.quit();
    if (someResult != null) {
        // gets executed
    }
```

Of course, *"blocking the UI thread is bad, m'kaaaaay"*. But I guess you know what you're doing.